# Installing Microsoft Edge demo on Windows 7 (requires Windows 10 SDK)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have got a Windows 7 machine and I seem to be unable to **install the Windows 10 SDK** (which is a pre-requisite to run the demo project linked below). I cannot upgrade to Windows 10.

Is there a way to get the MicrosoftEdge demo called "magic-mirror-demo" up an running **on Windows 7**?

Here is the link to the repository:
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/magic-mirror-demo

Comment: No you can't. Can you install Windows 10 on a VM?

Comment: the Windows 10 SDK can be installed fine in Windows 7, but Edge is Win10 exclusive